# Jupyterlabs Notebook and command line Python have different system path?

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook

**Question:** 
What's the best way to set a Jupyterlab's notebook to have the same sys.path as Python when it's run from the Mac terminal?

**Background:** 
I can use a python module (Beautiful Soup) successfully by starting Python from the Mac terminal (within a virtual environment named VENV). It installs, imports and works fine. But the Jupyterlabs notebook using the same VENV environment, won't import the very same module. I confirmed they are both using the same Python instance using the "Which Python" command, but terminal and notebook have a different sys.path, which appears to be restricting what the notebook can see.

What's the best way to handle this path inconsistency?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to make it work.

Thanks to Peter Bakke.

https://www.peterbakke.com/data-analysis/set-system-path-python-jupyter-notebooks/

I also installed BeautifulSoup4, rather than bs4.